# What to do with questions regarding server configuration?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have seen some question regarding server configurations, for instance "How do I install `[apache|nginx|letsencrypt]`?". These questions are obviously not related to Drupal. There is however also no a good reason for closing. The best option would be:

> Questions on **programming, PHP, SQL, etc.** that do not relate directly
>   to Drupal are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.

But the question is not about programming, PHP, SQL or anything similar, it is about server configuration.

I found this old meta issue: [Do we still want server administration questions?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/do-we-still-want-server-administration-questions) which makes me think there used to be the following option (probably from this earlier question: [Add other StackExchange network sites to off-topic close reason](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/add-other-stackexchange-network-sites-to-off-topic-close-reason/2623#2623)):

> If the question is a generic question about server configuration,
>   consider asking it on Server Fault, as long as the question is about
>   managing computer systems in a professional capacity.

I wonder why that has been removed, and if we can somewhat improve the closing of such questions. If I were to ask a question regarding server related stuff, I'd be surprised to see it closed with the reason I may not ask about programming. IMHO there should be at lease some message that we do not answer non-Drupal server related stuff here.

Comment: I was referring to the Help Center, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, which still contains that sentence.

Comment: Ah, I thought it used to be one of the close reasons. Thanks for clarifying. But can we add it as a close reason?

Comment: @Neograph734 We only have three custom close reasons, and are using them all.  We would either need to get rid of one, or edit this into an existing one.